# Recursive function in Scheme only returning the first item in list

Tags: recursion, lisp, scheme

My function only returns the first element - my base case. Maybe I have my recursion wrong and maybe I need some help with the functions in lisp.

The function needs to return the sum of all of the elements in a binary list converted to decimal. I opted to convert each element of the list to decimal FIRST, and then add the rest as they get converted. I have 2 functions. The first works well, convertToBinary :

```
(define (binaryToDecimal n)
   (cond [(zero? n) 0]
         [else (+ ( * 2 (binaryToDecimal (quotient n 10)))
                  (remainder n 10))]
         ))
```

The second one not so well:

```
(define (addBinary binaryList)
   (cond [(null? (cdr '(binaryList))) (binaryToDecimal (car binaryList))]
    [else 
     (cons (+ (binaryToDecimal (car binaryList)) 
              (addBinary (cdr '(binaryList)))))]
    ))
```

If I call the function with this:

```
(addBinary '(1101 111 10 101))
```

Then I get: 13. Which is the decimal conversion of 1101 (the first element in my list). I think obviously the problem is in my else condition but I am not seeing the problem and was hoping for some help. I searched around and read that using "cons" would construct (so to speak) the element in the list with the applied change. Not sure if this is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a couple of instances of `(cdr '(binaryList))`, which doesn't do what you expect. Perhaps you meant to use `(cdr binaryList)` instead. Anyway, your base case is a little funky too: I think your base case should be the empty list, and have it return 0 in that case:

```
(define (addBinary binaryList)
  (cond ((null? binaryList) 0)
        (else
         (+ (binaryToDecimal (car binaryList))
            (addBinary (cdr binaryList))))))
```

Comment: Ah hah! That fixed it! Thanks a million - I've been beating my head on the wall (not literally) for an hour trying to figure it out. It kills me when it's something so silly ;)